# C#.NET check if the object is null or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am I doing this correct? I'm interested to know the possible reasons why its failing?

```
Object obj = Find(id); //returns the object. if not found, returns null
if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
{
     //do stuff
}
else
{
     //do stuff
}
```

Find Method (Uses ORM Dapper). Performed unit tests on this, I believe there is no problem with this method.

```
public Object Find(string id)
{
     var result = this.db.QueryMultiple("GetDetails", new { Id = id }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
     var obj = result.Read<Object>().SingleOrDefault();
     return obj;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine, but you could also use `obj != null`

Comment: What's the type of `obj`? Is it a reference type or a value type?

Comment: It is a reference type. It also fails on `obj!=null`

Comment: Can you update your question with the code of the `Find` method? Also, what's the value of `id` that makes `obj!=null` fails?

Comment: Have you tried to debug and check the `obj` value after `Find` method is executed?

Comment: Don't declare variables as object if you know what the actual type is going to be. Use the explicit type.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
   Object obj = Find(id); //returns the object. if not found, returns null
   if (obj != null)
   {
        //do stuff when obj is not null
   }
   else
   {
        //do stuff when obj is null
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do following. Why negate the null check unnecessarily?

```
Object obj = Find(id); //returns the object. if not found, returns null

if (obj == null)
{
        //do stuff when obj is null
}
else
{
        //do stuff when obj is not null
}
```